# YARN - Number of map/reduce tasks that can run in a container

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am implemetting a MR ETL job and I have only mapper tasks and no reducer tasks.

I always see only one mapper running inside a container.

Is it possible to run multiple mapper inside a container or only one map/reduce task can run inside a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container runs only one task (Map, reduce or whatever else). However multiple containers can run on the same machine at the same time, if there are enough resources available.